# What is event handler means in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and was confused by the concept of event handler, can someone give me an specific example?

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
});
```

Is the following function inside of this click event = "event handler"? or the "on(click)" is the event handler?

```
function(){alert($(this).text())}
```

Comment: Check out https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler means the function, when you add click event the action performed by the function like

```html
function(){alert($(this).text())}
```

is the event handler.

Comment: Note the event handler does not need to be an anonymous inline function - it can be a named function, and must be called accordingly `$().click(myfunc)` and not `$().click(myfunc())` which gets asked a couple of times a week at least (separate from the question being asked here).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.on` method registers an event listener. That listener reacts when it hears an event has been triggered (that it was supposed to listen to). In that case the listener then hands the event it received over to the eventhandler, who handles the events. `$(el).on('click'...` registers the listener to listen for click events on el. In `... function(event) {/*handle event*/});` the anynomous function is the eventhandler.

Comment: And don't forget that in the OP's example there is another event listener  - the anonymous function of the `$(document).ready` event